# JS: Submit form and render results on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, get

Apologies in advance for my naivete, I'm definitely not a web developer.

I'm trying to take the content of a simple HTML form, submit this as a GET request to a very lightweight server I'm running, and render the result on the same page. Here's my code so far:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var submit_button = $('#submit_form');
        
        submit_button.click(function() {
            
            var word = $('word').val();
            
            var data = '?word=' + word;
            
            var update_div = $('#update_div');
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://35.45.55.65:5000/api',
                data: data,
                success:function(html){
                    update_div.html(html);
                console.log("Done");
                console.log(html)
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <h1>Enter a word to check</h1>
    <form id="my_form">
        Word: <br/> <input name="word" id="word" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <div id="update_div"></div>
```

From everything I've read, this code should work? However, the form isn't getting submitted at all, instead, the GET request is getting appended to the current URL without the JS code even running -- like so: `currentURL.com/test.html?word=hello+world`

I'm really not sure what's going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks :)

Comment: use this `var word = $('#word').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the form. that's the reason you have those values attached to the URL.

```
submit_button.click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 // rest of code
}
```